# How to load balance request to list of URIs in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, spring-cloud-gateway

I don't have eureka, load balancer and so on. I want to load balance the request to list of URIs on which instances of backend run.

```html
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: myService-endpoints
          uri: myServiceIp1, myServiceIp2
          predicates:
            - Path=/myservice/**
```

myServiceIp1 and myServiceIp2 are my backend service IPs. How can I achieve load balancing in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using service registry, you can still use load-balancing in your app. You will just need to use the [`SimpleDiscoveryClient`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#simplediscoveryclient) that allows you to set your service instance URIs via a property file, like so:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.client.simple.instances.service1[0].uri=http://s11:8080
```

Then you can just follow the guides for [setting up load-balanced routes in Gateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#reactive-loadbalancer-client-filter), like so:

```
spring:
 cloud:
   gateway:
     routes:
     - id: myRoute
       uri: lb://service
       predicates:
       - Path=/service/**
```